# How to encode JSON in php

Tags: php, json

I am getting some data from mysql server using php and encoding it into json.

This is what i have so far:

```
[
    {
        "ImageID": "1",
        "ImageName": "Hakuna Matata",
        "Details": "some text"
    },
    {
        "ImageID": "2",
        "ImageName": "Hakuna Matata2",
        "Details": "some text"
    }
]
```

I would like to add an array in "details" but i dont know how to achieve this. Like in this format:

```
[
    {
        "ImageID": "1",
        "ImageName": "Hakuna Matata",
        "Details": ["some text","some text"]
    },
    {
        "ImageID": "2",
        "ImageName": "Hakuna Matata2",
        "Details": ["some text","some text"]
    }
]
```

I am new to dealing with php so please be gentle :)

Here is my php file:

```
<?php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("weHappening");

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM all_events WHERE 1  ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);

$resultArray = array();

while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))

{

$arrCol = array();

for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)

{

$arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];

}

array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);

}

mysql_close($objConnect);

if (json_last_error() ===
JSON_ERROR_NONE){
//do something

echo json_encode($resultArray);

} else {
//error its not json
}

?>
```

Comment: wrong terminology: you're **EN** coding into json. decoding would take json text and convert to something else. and technically this has nothing to do with json. you're simply building your PHP array wrong. json encoding is basically 1:1 operation. if your PHP array is wrong, the json structure will be "wrong" as well.

Comment: Fixed it..sorry for the mistake

Comment: @Marc B like I said..newbie

Answer (score 0):

Turn:

```
$arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
```

Into:

```
$field_name = mysql_field_name($objQuery, $i);
if ($field_name == 'Details') {
    $value = [$objResult[$i]];
} else {
    $value = $objResult[$i];
}
$arrCol[$field_name] = $value;
```

Of course this is not tested but you should get the idea.

Comment: I tried your code..it gave me this output:[
    {
        "title": null,
        "image": null,
        "time": null,
        "da": null,
        "where": null,
        "details": null
    }]

Comment: I'm sure there's something I should get from your answer but I kinda still don't..newbie issues